# How can I create a horizontal curly brace in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

How can I create a horizontal curly brace in Adobe Illustrator like the image below?

I actually typed `{` and converted it to be able to rotate and resize it however the effect wasn't beautiful.

I have made the below image using Paint just to show you what I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One could do this manually....

- Draw a path
- Round the corners
- Reflect a copy
- Join the 2 paths
- Adjust

[image]

Barring this, if one wishes to use a type glyph as a basis, it *really* depends upon the glyph itself. Some typeface curly braces will allow for more "stretching" than others.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it the way Scott suggests, but if you need a shape that you can resize without squishing or stretching, there is something else you could try in addition to this

1. Create one half of the design as per Scott's suggestion
2. Add a Transform reflect effect from the Appearance Panel
3. If you want to rescale the object, select the end anchors, and move them with the arrow key on your keyboard.

Because the Transform is a live effect, it will extend automatically to the other side, and because you are moving the anchors rather than stretching there won't be any distortion.

An example

[image]

Comment: Love the transform effect `:)` The only thing with the transform effect, for me in this instance, is that you don't really have control over that middle joint. You can't round it or make it sharp. You kind of have to deal with whatever you get. [It works better with rounded caps, but not so well with squared caps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NepgB.png). I'd be inclined to create a Symbol with 9-point scaling to keep the ends nice and curved. And as a single object, the Width Tool or Stroke Profile can also add a bit of ["flair"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6dIG.png).

Comment: @Scott - yeah, rounded end caps are probably going to be required if you go down the transform effect route.